# How to grep two patterns at once

Tags: grep

Often times I have to do so commandline thing where I pipe to grep and want matches for two different expressions. ( An OR match A OR B. )

For example I want to grep the output of generate_out for either foo[0-9]+ or bar[0-9]+. I of course could just execute twice:

```
generate_out| grep "foo[0-9]+"   
generate_out| grep "bar[0-9]+"
```

but often generate_out is expensive and I would rather not want to run it twice ( or store it's output ). Rather I would like to just use one expression:

```
generate_out| grep "foo[0-9]+ OR bar[0-9]+"
```

of course this will not work but I would like the equivalent expression which will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an alternation in your regex:

```
generate_out | grep -E '(foo|bar)[0-9]+'
```

The use of `-E` enables ERE features, of this which is one. (By default, grep only supports BRE; some implementations of BRE -- such as GNU's -- may have special syntax for enabling ERE features; in the GNU case, `\|` in BRE is equivalent to `|` in ERE; however, it's not portable to rely on such extensions instead of just turning on ERE properly).

---

`egrep` is a backwards-compatibility synonym for `grep -E`; however, [only the latter is specified as a requirement by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html).

Comment: answer deleted, parallel edition of two near than equal answers: generate_out | egrep "foo[0-9]+|bar[0-9]+".

Answer (score 4):

use grep's `-e` option to specify multiple patterns that are "OR'ed":

```
$ seq 15 | grep -e 5 -e 3
3
5
13
15
```

Answer (score 3):

Use awk for simplicity:

```
generate_out| awk '/foo[0-9]+/ || /bar[0-9]+/'
```

which of course could be simplified in this particular case to:

```
generate_out| awk '/(foo|bar)[0-9]+/'
```

but in general you want to use awk for simple, consistent `OR`s and `AND`s of regexps:

```
cmd | grep -E 'foo.*bar|bar.*foo'
cmd | awk '/foo/ && /bar/'

cmd | grep 'foo' | grep -v 'bar'
cmd | awk '/foo/ && !/bar/'

cmd | grep -E 'foo|bar'
cmd | awk '/foo/ || /bar/'      (or awk '/foo|bar/')

cmd | grep -E 'foo|bar' | grep -E -v 'foo.*bar|bar.*foo'
cmd | awk '(/foo/ && !/bar/) || (/bar/ && !/foo/)'
```

Comment: Overkill for the OP here, but other people finding this question are likely to need this more comprehensive answer (for instance, to be able to require multiple matches within a single line without regard to their order -- which is tolerable with grep when having only two values but unreasonable beyond that point), so this has my upvote.